# Как передать только новый файл на сервер

Tags: winscp

Написал скрипт с возобновлением передачи файла на сервер.

```
    @echo off

"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
  /command ^
    "open ftp://XXXXXXX:XXXXXXX@192.X.X.X/ -rawsettings AddressFamily=1" ^
    "lcd D:\SQLBackup\archive" ^
    "cd /BACKUP/W_C" ^
    "put rab_20220916.bak -resume -neweronly -speed=0 -resumesupport=on"
```

Возможно ли использовать маску для передачи файла по последней дате. В локальной папке по пути D:\SQLBackup\archive формируются  backup файлы в формате .bak раз в неделю в субботу(rab_20220910,rab_20220916). Как можно заставить winscp закачивать на удаленный сервер файл, сформированный в субботу в течение 3-5 дней . Батник будет запускаться через планировщик windows c 18 до 8. Если это можно сделать по маске, то как будет выглядеть команда? Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Код сработал с параметром  -latest *.bak